# Error: listen EADDRINUSE node JS

Tags: node.js, macos, sails.js

I have 2 Sails application, one depend on another.
First I'm running at port 1337 the second at 1338.
All was working fine until yesterday. Have Mac, now I can run only that at 1337 and then 1338 at the second terminal tab giving me the:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::1338
If I'm running killall -9 node
It killing the 1337 then when I'm trying rerun 1337 again I'm getting Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::1337 also,
If I will run on tab of 1337 the killall -9 node 
Im getting: No matching processes belonging to you were found
And cannot run any application.
Will help only restarting terminal

Is there any system setting that I can adjust?
I'm pretty new Mac user.

Comment: Have you had a look in Activity Monitor? You may have a renegade `node` process somewhere.

Comment: Yes I just checked, there is no node processes, I Just restarted terminal then lunched 1337 again then saw just that process

Comment: What does `lsof -n | grep 1337 | grep LISTEN` show? That might be able to find the offending process.

Comment: have you started your node in cluster mode?

Comment: unfortunately nothing. Just going to second line

Comment: About cluster mode, I do not know hot to check it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys just find out the problem.
It is so stupid.
I'm using tunnnelclick for vpn and it is running on port 1337.
Thank you guys for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Some process is occupying your 1338 port.

I am not using a mac myself, but I think this might help you check what is using the port, just switch out "80" for "1338"

http://www.databasically.com/2011/06/02/mac-os-x-find-the-program-running-on-a-port/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ps ax | grep node
```

a list similar to the following

```
7200 pts/1    Sl+    0:00 node /usr/bin/nodemon app.js
11431 pts/1    S+     0:00 sh -c node app.js
11432 pts/1    Sl+    0:02 node app.js
11971 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

kill all node processes by

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

now run your apps(both port again).
If you still get errors then check for the availability of that port with

```
netstat -anp | grep <portNumber>
```

Comment: command ps ax | grep node result: 807 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep node. Then Im killing it with sudo kill -9 <807>, if will run ps ax | grep node again will get:  811 s000  S+     0:00.01 grep node

Comment: looks like something restarting that node,

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS Code in Windows, You would need to first KILL the previous instances of your Node-App

Open **BASH** terminal in VS Code and run below command

`cmd "/C TASKKILL /IM node.exe /F"`